# Reactjs Array.slice(start, end) not working

Tags: reactjs, slice

I have a problem with the `slice()` function.

My code:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state({
    data: props.data
  })
}

//my function
onSliceData = () => {
  let data = this.state.data;
  let sliceData = data.slice(0,5);
  return sliceData;
}
```

My problem is my function does not return anything. When I `console.log(data)` in **onSliceData** I receive result like this:

[image]
And when I `console.log(sliceData)` I just receive []
[image]
I try using Object.keys to convert data to array but maybe not working.
I need some help.

Comment: Object.keys doesn't convert an object to an array.

Comment: yes. Object.keys just returns array is the key of object. I wanna return array of object , example: [{}, {},...] what should I do?

Comment: Check my answer and onSliceData should return an array of objects if props.data is an array of objects :)

Comment: I think there's a problem with storing data, not the `slice` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Array.from(data).slice`.
It worked for me same on ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the props being received have data(which is an array)

In the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { // assign the state with an js object instead of calling it as a func.
    data: props.data
  }
}
```

Try this:

```
onSliceData = () => {
  let data = [...this.state.data]; // spreading will return a new array
  let sliceData = data.slice(0,5);
  return sliceData;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but not working to me :( it returns [] nothing inside :(

Comment: when and where are you calling onSliceData?

Comment: I call at `componentDidMount(){ this.onSliceData()}`

Comment: and where are you logging the returned value?

Comment: I get data from mysql by axios

Comment: Okay, I'm asking where have you placed the `console.log()` after calling slicedata?

Comment: so you're able to see a nonempty array in the first `console.log(data)` but the next `console.log(sliceData)` is an empty array?

Comment: sorry, I'm late, but here is result return when I call `console.log(data)` and `console.log(sliceData)`  https://imgur.com/a/tfhApW5

Comment: this is very strange indeed, can you provide a stackBlitz replicating this issue.

Comment: @Simpa407 your stackBlitz has some errors, anyway I created a new [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dehxje?file=DataTable.js) replicating your scenario, I'm passing a hardcoded array of two objects and in the DataTable component, the slicing works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I found this with the help of w3schools):

**`let sliceData = data.toString().slice(0,5);`**

I tried this method and it worked just fine!